# Mysql table of teams, Selecting the captain and another player

Tags: php, mysql

I have two Tables

```
|   Team    |        |   Player   |
+-----------+        +------------+
| id        |        | player_id  |
| player_id |        | player     |
| captain   |
```

I have `INNER JOIN players ON Team.player_id = Player.player_id`

Which will, for example, display:

```
  id |        player         |    captain
 ----+-----------------------+-------------
   1 |    Jeremiah Gilbert   |
   1 |    John Sidbury       |
   1 |    George Morrell     |
   1 |    William Mathiss    |       C
   1 |    John Parlement     |
   1 |    William Lester     |
   1 |    George Partick     |
   1 |    William Thornnton  |
```

I have hundreds of teams, each team consists of eight players, on average a player can be in 20 teams any player can be a captain for a team.

For example:
I want to search in `team` where `William Mathiss` is Captain (`C`) and `George Partick` is a player in the same team. In the above example, they are both in team `1`.

I will want to put this in a PHP search form, so I will have two fields one for the player and the other for the captain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I came up with for finding the same two players in teams, Now I just need to add the attribute captain for one of the players.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    b.player,
    c.player
FROM
    Team a 
        JOIN player b ON a.player_id=b.player_id
        JOIN Team d
        JOIN player c ON d.player_id=c.player_id
WHERE
     b.player = 'Player one' AND c.player = 'Player two'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT t.id,
       p.player,
       t.captain
FROM Team t
    JOIN Player p ON (t.player_id = p.player_id)
      Where p.player = 'Player_name'
        AND t.captain = 'Captain_Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure first.
Currently you have users, teams and players? The teams should not contain players. If a user can be captain of a team, be a normal member of a team and be in multiple teams at once, you should have a table for teams, users and a relation table with foreign keys to the two main tables.
When doing that, you can join the user table twice and filter by users as captains and team members separately. You can do it already without changing the structure but I highly recommend.
In PHP you can then use PDO for a prepared statement, make a "bindParam()" or "bindValue()" twice (or just pass an array into the "execute()" but then you can't validate the data type first).

Comment: I don't think there are `users`, OP didn't mention that in his table. I think he meant 'players' instead of 'users'.

Comment: Yes I did mean players